# Compare Strings in Swift unit test

Tags: string, swift, unit-testing

How do you test whether two Strings are equal in a Swift unit test?  I've tried the `==` operator but it doesn't recognize it:

```
import XCTest
@testable import MyProject

class MyProject: XCTestCase {

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
}

override func tearDown() {
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    super.tearDown()
}

func testExample() {
    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
    XCTAssertNil(nil, "This test works")
}

func toJSONTest() {
    let currentLocation = deviceLocation(timestamp: "2015-11-02 16:32:15 +0000",latitude: "40.2736577695212",longitude: "-111.715408331498")
    var MyProjectStatuses = [MyProjectStatus(id: "", currentLocation: currentLocation)]
    let json = ""
    XCTAssertTrue(json == "")
}

func testPerformanceExample() {
    // This is an example of a performance test case.
    self.measureBlock {
        // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.
    }
}

}
```

And the actual method being tested from MyProject.swift:

```
func toJSON ()->String{
    var json = ""
    json = "{\"myproject_status\":"
    json = json + "{\"id\":\"" + self.Id + "\""
    return json 
}
```

This part:

`XCTAssertTrue(json == "")`

Throws:

`Operator is not a known binary operator`

Comment: Please show the _whole_ unit test file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `toJSONTest` is not a test. Change the name to `testToJSON`.

This works fine on my machine:

```
func testToJSON() {
    let json = ""
    XCTAssertTrue(json == "")
}
```

The test runs, and passes. However, I would probably write it like this:

```
func testToJSON() {
    let json = ""
    XCTAssertEqual(json, "", "They are not equal")
}
```

Comment: Also, observe that your test, if it were a test, nowhere calls `func toJSON`, so it is not actually testing anything.

Comment: It was then I changed it to figure out how to compare strings.  It stills throws the same error with the name testToJSON()

Comment: Works fine on my machine.

Comment: I'm using XCode Version 7.1 beta 3 (7B85) if that matters

Comment: Why are you using a beta? 7.1 went final some time ago. I don't think it does matter, but it's a silly thing to be doing.

Answer (score 5):

Although this question is explicitly about how to compare two Strings in a Swift unit test, what's implicit in the question is how to compare two JSON Strings. I want to point out that the right thing to do when comparing two JSON strings is to parse the JSON Strings to a Foundation object with the [JSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization) class and then to compare the resulting Foundation objects. This approach takes care of the problem of the two JSON Strings having slightly different formatting or fields in a different order. So, for example, it's important that `"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}"` and `"{\"b\":2,\"a\":1}"` are deemed to be equal because they are logically equal.

Here's a Swift function I put together which helps with this comparison:

```
class JSONAssert {

    class func assertEquals(expected: String, actual: String) {
    
        let expectedData = Data(expected.utf8)
        let actualData = Data(actual.utf8)
    
        let expectedObject: Any
        let actualObject: Any
    
        do {
            expectedObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: expectedData, options: [])
        } catch {
            XCTFail("Failed constructing a Foundation object from `expected` (i.e. \(expected)): \(error)")
            return
        }
    
        do {
            actualObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: actualData, options: [])
        } catch {
            XCTFail("Failed constructing a Foundation object from `actual` (i.e. \(actual)): \(error)")
            return
        }
    
        guard let expectedDictionary = expectedObject as? NSDictionary else {
            XCTFail("Failed casting expected object (i.e. \(expectedObject)) to an NSDictionary")
            return
        }
    
        guard let actualDictionary = actualObject as? NSDictionary else {
            XCTFail("Failed casting actual object (i.e. \(actualObject)) to an NSDictionary")
            return
        }
    
        XCTAssertEqual(expectedDictionary, actualDictionary)
    }
}
```